# Problems migrating on mysql2. Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm running `bundle exec rake db:create` and then bundle exec rake db:migrate` and I run into this error when migrating:

```
 bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20110125192211 InitialDigitizationWork: migrating ==========================
-- create_table(:digitizations)
   -> 0.0170s
-- add_index(:digitizations, :submission_code, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0156s
-- create_table(:digitized_pieces)
   -> 0.0180s
-- add_index(:digitized_pieces, :digitization_id)
   -> 0.0113s
-- create_table(:digitized_views)
   -> 0.0235s
-- add_index(:digitized_views, :digitized_piece_id, {:null=>false})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Unknown key: :null. Valid keys are: :unique, :order, :name, :where, :length, :internal, :using, :algorithm,
```

It's my first time using Mysql (I'm used to Postgresql) I seem to have Mysql:

```
 mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 31
Server version: 5.7.20 Homebrew
```

This is my `database.yml` file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: arthouse_dev
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  #socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

legacy_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: arthouse_leg_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a bug, you cannot have `null: false` for an index.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `default: null` constrain to an index, the error you see states that explicitly:

> Unknown key: :null. Valid keys are: :unique, :order, :name, :where,
>   :length, :internal, :using, :algorithm

Remove the default null on those indexes and you should be fine.